# Can't seem to close the application properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I have been using this code inside my main()

```
int go3 = 0;
std::atomic<bool> is_done{ false };

int camera() {
    const int WIDTH = 640;
    const int HEIGHT = 480;
    cv::VideoCapture cap(1);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 60);
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::Mat srcImage = cv::imread("img/zoom log_50sm.png", -1);
    cv::Mat mask;
    vector<cv::Mat> rgbLayer;
    // First, create a virtual camera instance with scCreateCamera().
    // A virtual camera is a source of a video image stream.
    // The dimension width and height can be arbitrary positive numbers
    // which are multiples of four.
    // The third argument framerate is used to make sending frames at regular intervals.
    // This framerate argument can be omitted, and the default framerate is 60.
    // If you want to send every frame immediately without the frame rate regulator,
    // specify 0 to the framerate argument, then it will be a variable frame rate.
    scCamera cam = scCreateCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 60);

    // Here, we wait for an application to connect to this camera.
    // You can comment out this line to start sending frames immediately
    // no matter there is a receiver or not.
    scWaitForConnection(cam);
    while (go3 != 1)
    {
        //Mat frame;
        cap.read(frame);
        cv::Mat result;

        //overlayImage(frame, srcImage, result, cv::Point(16, 80));
        //srcImage.copyTo(frame(cv::Rect(20, 75, srcImage.cols, srcImage.rows)), mask);
        // Draw bouncing balls.
        //balls.move(1.0f / 60.0f);
        //balls.draw(image.data());

        // Send the image as a newly captured frame of the camera.
        scSendFrame(cam, frame.ptr());
    }
    is_done = true;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    thread thread2(camera);
    thread2.detach();
    MyApp app;
    app.Run();
    //thread2.join();
    go3 = 1;
    //thread2.join();
    if (is_done == true) {
        using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for, sleep_until
        using namespace std::chrono; // nanoseconds, system_clock, seconds
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is every time I try to close the program, the window will hang and not do anything but the thread2 closes or it gives a fatal exception. Is there something I'm missing here to cleanly close the application?

Comment: Why do you detach the thread?

Comment: Add `cap.release()` at the end.

Comment: Your program is not reproduceable, for example what is the relation between `App` and `thread2`, and my  second thought is that to change `if (is_done == true) {` to `while(!is_done)` you have to wait until your thread finished and then exit the program

Comment: the spawned thread will keep the process alive. you need to end that thread in an orderly fashion.

Comment: How do I end the thread properly then? I have tried every which way, I also tried Saeed Masoomis method.

Comment: I think detaching is not a good option. After detaching, you lost the control to the thread2. Is app.run() running in another thread (not blocking the main thread) or in the main thread (blocking main thread)?

Comment: It seems that the problem was scWaitForConnection(cam);, as after the while loop was over it was waiting for the cam even that the cam has been destroyed, removing this has fixed it.